# Make generic method with template with IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, templates

I am looking to combine two function which have similar code but different Type of variables. I want to use the T type inside `IEnumerable` but it doesn't seem to work.

Method 1:

```
public static IList<ListItem> AppendTopMakesToList(this IEnumerable<ListItem> options, bool appendSeparatorRow = true)
{
    if (options == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("RACQ.JoinMembership.Top10CarMakes"))) 
        return options.ToList();

    var topmakes = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("RACQ.JoinMembership.Top10CarMakes").Split('|').ToList().ConvertAll(d => d.ToLower());
    var filteredMakes = options.Where(x => topmakes.Any(y => y.Contains(x.Text.ToLower()))).ToList();//getting all the makes from the listItems

    if (appendSeparatorRow)
    {
        var separatorListItem = new ListItem("------------------", "------------------", false);
        separatorListItem.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true"); //disabling the separator item so that it can't be selected
        filteredMakes.Add(separatorListItem);
    }

    var items = options.ToList();
    items.InsertRange(0, filteredMakes);

    return items;
}
```

Method 2:

```
public static IList<Make> AppendTopMakesToList(this IEnumerable<Make> options, bool appendSeparatorRow = true)
{
    if (options == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("RACQ.JoinMembership.Top10CarMakes"))) 
       return options.ToList();

    var topmakes = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("RACQ.JoinMembership.Top10CarMakes").Split('|').ToList().ConvertAll(d => d.ToLower());
    var filteredMakes = options.Where(x => topmakes.Any(y => y.Contains(x.Code.ToLower()))).ToList();//getting all the makes from the listItems

    if (appendSeparatorRow)
    {
        var separatorListItem = new Make()
                {
                    Code = "------------------",
                    Description = "------------------"
                };

                filteredMakes.Add(separatorListItem);
            }

            var items = options.ToList();
            items.InsertRange(0, filteredMakes);

            return items;
        }
    }
}
```

The functions are doing exactly same a part from the return type `IList<Make>` and `IList<ListItem>` which is passed on the parameter type of `IEnumerable<Make>` and `IEnumerable<ListItem>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
public static IList<T> AppendItems<T>(this IEnumerable<T> options, Action<T> blankFactory, bool appendSeparatorRow = true)
        {
            if (options == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("RACQ.JoinMembership.Top10CarMakes"))) return options.ToList();
            var topmakes = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("RACQ.JoinMembership.Top10CarMakes").Split('|').ToList().ConvertAll(d => d.ToLower());
            var filteredMakes = options.Where(x => topmakes.Any(y => y.Contains(x.Code.ToLower()))).ToList();//getting all the makes from the listItems
            if (appendSeparatorRow)
            {
                var separatorListItem = blankFactory();
                filteredMakes.Add(separatorListItem);
            }
            var items = options.ToList();
            items.InsertRange(0, filteredMakes);
            return items;
        }
```

And then you can use it like so:

```
var whatever = new List<ListItem>():


AppendItems(whatever, () => {
                var separatorListItem = new ListItem("------------------", "------------------", false);
                separatorListItem.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");
    return separatorListItem;

}, true);
```

Comment: Isn't also can be called using `whatever.AppendItems(()=>{// blah blah})`, since the first parameter has `this` keyword. this will work either way :D

Comment: Yeah, @keysl is right, this is an extension method, so you can use the above syntax, too. or `using static` and what i wrote. or specify class name like `WhateverExtensions.` and call it that way. C# is flexible :)